# Mysql Query takes too long to execute. Why?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to make my query more faster ? or is there other way to do this kind of query? i have 12k row's inside of table.

```
SELECT * from tbl_attendance_master tbl1 , tbl_attendance_master tbl2 
where tbl1.id > tbl2.id and 
tbl1.employees_id = tbl2.employees_id and 
tbl1.in_time = tbl2.in_time AND
tbl1.out_time = tbl2.out_time
```

[Query Execute time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpojy.png)

Comment: which mysql version?

Comment: Server version: 5.6.44

Comment: try add index `create index id_index ON tbl_attendance_master (id) `

Comment: Can you give me example of that query ? I'm not familiar in that `create index` syntax.

Comment: just run this `create index id_index ON tbl_attendance_master (id) ` to create index

Comment: The execution still the same. it give's me 201 seconds execution time.

Comment: On top of your query, type `EXPLAIN` and post the result here.

Comment: Also consider using join..  Change the comma to 'JOIN' in between those two tables and change `WHERE` to `ON` like this > `SELECT * from tbl_attendance_master tbl1 JOIN tbl_attendance_master tbl2 
ON .... `

Answer (score 1):

try add index

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tbl_attendance_master`
ADD INDEX `employees_id_in_time_out_time` (`employees_id`, `in_time`, `out_time`),
```

hope this can help!